# How to change height of fregment & View in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface, height

I working on app that uses Google Maps API v2, in first place user can access a layout with the maps on full screen and with a small frame (let's call it BtmFrame) with text saying how much Clubs are in the current city. When user clicks on the BtmFrame, I need to get the height of the maps smaller and the BtmFrame bigger so it can contain the Clubs list.

I can simply change view height but I seeking to do it with animation.

> [image]

Comment: using a [PropertyAnimation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) on the view height should work.

Comment: @FoamyGuy note there are some issues with animations: [issue 4990](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4990) and [issue 4782 comment 1](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4782#c1)